# Разбивка мультиполигона OSM на отдельные полигоны для Яндекс. Карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, openstreetmap, geojson

В клубе Яндекс. Карт спросил, можно ли отрисовать мультиполигон GeoJSON, который тянется с nominatim.openstreetmap.org, средствами API Яндекс. Карт. Сказали, нужно разбить мультиполигон на отдельные полигоны, а потом уже рисовать.

Что я делаю не так? Вот код @tutankhamun, который пытаюсь допилить:

```
ymaps.ready(function() {
    // 0. Создаем карту, например так:
    var map,
        regionName = "Московская область, Одинцовский район",
        center = [37.6174976, 55.6506828],
        zoom = 7;

    map = new ymaps.Map('karta', {
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom,
        controls: []
    });
    // 1. Запрашиваем через геокодер район (у Яндекса этой возможности пока нет, придется пользоваться OSM)
    var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search";
    var jsondata = $.getJSON(url, {
            q: regionName,
            format: "json",
            polygon_geojson: 1
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(ix, place) {
                // 2. Разбиваем мультиполигон на полигоны.
                if ("MultiPolygon" == place.geojson.type) {
                    place.geojson.coordinates.forEach(function(coords) {
                        var feat = {
                            'type': 'Polygon',
                            'coordinates': coords
                        };
                        var p = new ymaps.Polygon(feat.coordinates, {
                            hintContent: "Одинцовский район"
                        }, {
                            fillColor: '#6699ff',
                            // Делаем полигон прозрачным для событий карты.
                            interactivityModel: 'default#transparent',
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            opacity: 0.3
                        });
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(feat));
                    });
                } else if ("relation" == place.osm_type) {
                    // 3. Создаем полигон с нужными координатами
                    var p = new ymaps.Polygon(place.geojson.coordinates, {
                        hintContent: "Одинцовский район"
                    }, {
                        fillColor: '#6699ff',
                        // Делаем полигон прозрачным для событий карты.
                        interactivityModel: 'default#transparent',
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        opacity: 0.3
                    });
                    // 4. Добавляем полигон(ы) на карту
                    map.geoObjects.add(p);
                    map.setBounds(map.geoObjects.getBounds())
                }
            });
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

Comment: Какую задачу вы хотите решить и что именно не получается? Опубликуйте _ваш_ код

Comment: так вроде все опубликовано.
пункт 2. Разбиваем мультиполигон на полигоны. - проблема в этом пункте. В итоге ничего не отрисовывается

Comment: Давайте поговорим в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47783)

Comment: не хватает репутации для чата

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел свою ошибку. Во втором пункте забыл инициировать добавление полигонов на карту. Вот полностью рабочий код для нанесения на Яндекс.Карты областей и районов (полигонов и мультиполигонов) с OpenStreetMap:

```
<div id="karta" class="karta-def"></div>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
ymaps.ready(function() {
    // 0. Создаем карту
    var map,
        regionName = "Московская область, Одинцовский район",
        center = [37.6174976, 55.6506828],
        zoom = 7;

    map = new ymaps.Map('karta', {
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom,
        controls: []
    });
    // 1. Запрашиваем через геокодер район (у Яндекса этой возможности пока нет, придется пользоваться OSM)
    var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search";
    var jsondata = $.getJSON(url, {
            q: regionName,
            format: "json",
            polygon_geojson: 1
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(ix, place) {
                // 2. Если район состоит из нескольких полигонов - разбиваем мультиполигон на отдельные полигоны (API Яндекс.Карт не умеет рисовать мультиполигоны GeoJSON).
                if ("MultiPolygon" == place.geojson.type) {
                    place.geojson.coordinates.forEach(function(coords) {
                        var feat = {
                            'type': 'Polygon',
                            'coordinates': coords
                        };
                        var p = new ymaps.Polygon(feat.coordinates, {
                            hintContent: regionName
                        }, {
                            fillColor: '#6699ff',
                            interactivityModel: 'default#transparent',
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            opacity: 0.3
                        });
                        // 2.1 Добавляем полигоны на карту
                        map.geoObjects.add(p);
                        map.setBounds(map.geoObjects.getBounds())
                    });
                // 3. В другом случае создаем полигон с нужными координатами
                } else if ("relation" == place.osm_type) {
                    var p = new ymaps.Polygon(place.geojson.coordinates, {
                        hintContent: regionName
                    }, {
                        fillColor: '#6699ff',
                        interactivityModel: 'default#transparent',
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        opacity: 0.3
                    });
                    // 3.1 Добавляем полигон на карту
                    map.geoObjects.add(p);
                    map.setBounds(map.geoObjects.getBounds())
                }
            });
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
</script>
```